# Ability to show validation rule errors next to Stage on VF page when restricting some stage values using selectoption

Tags: visualforce, validation-rule, selectlist, selectoption

Here's my vf page:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Stage" id="stageerrors">
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:selectList value="{!opp.opp.StageName}" multiselect="false" size="1"  >
<apex:selectOptions value="{!stageValues}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="probability,messages,stageerrors" />

</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:column>
```

and my Controller method for values:

```
public List<SelectOption> getstageValues(){

List<SelectOption> values = new List<SelectOption>();

   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
    if(f.getValue() != 'Completed.Expired – 100%' && f.getValue()!='Canceled – 100%'){
      values.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
      }
   }       
   system.debug('values@@'+values);
   return values ;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Currently, the error message(error messages from Stage validation rules) is shown at the top of the page and I am trying to display it next to the field/ Column Stage

Comment: you can create a visualforce component to show the error below the selectList. Here is an example for that kind of component http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/visualforce-input-validation-component.html